# How can we copy or download files from windows share path(UNC) to linux servers in Azure Devops tool/TFS?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to copy war and ear files from windows share path(UNC) to linux target servers where jboss jvm is running and then deploy these files using our custom script. this is for applications that are still not using tfs to do their build. i tried download from file share task in azure devops but that is only copying to the agent location but not to the target server. if anyone has come across this situation and found a solution please do share your thoughts. appreciate it. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use two tasks/steps to handle this situation.

1. Copy/download files from windows share path(UNC) to a folder path in build agent machine, such as `$(Agent.BuildDirectory)`
2. Copy files from a source folder to a target folder on a remote Linux server machine over SSH.

Since you have successfully download from file share task in Azure DevOps to agent machine. Then you just need to use **Copy Files Over SSH** task.

> Use this task in a build or release pipeline to copy files from a
>   source folder to a target folder on a remote machine over SSH.
>
> This task allows you to connect to a remote machine using SSH and copy
>   files matching a set of minimatch patterns from specified source
>   folder to target folder on the remote machine. Supported protocols for
>   file transfer are SFTP and SCP via SFTP. In addition to Linux, macOS
>   is partially supported.

More detail configuration about this task please refer official link here-- [Copy Files Over SSH task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/copy-files-over-ssh?view=azure-devops)