# Cannot access network shared drive in unattended mode using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I am new to powershell so would need need to resolve this issue.
We are trying to execute a powershell script via Azure devops pipelines and the script is made to access a network shared drive to identify a particular file.
The script runs perfectly fine in the gui session and is able to get the file.
However when we run it from AZ pipelines, it fails stating the access is denied.
The user being used in AZ Pipelines has admin access over the file.

The N/w drive path looks something like this.

```
\\ServerName\builds\PACKAGES\MainMasterBuildDrop\MainScheduledBuild\axmodel
```

Code ::

```
    $locr = "\\ServerName\builds\PACKAGES\MainMasterBuildDrop\MainScheduledBuild\axmodel"
    $axfiler = Get-ChildItem -Path $locr | Select FullName | ft -hidetableheaders | Out-String
    $filever = $($($axfiler.split("\")[-1]).Split("_")[-1]).Replace(".axmodel", "")
```

Error ::

```
2022-01-14T07:19:22.6339088Z o -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'C:\User
2022-01-14T07:19:22.6339869Z s\SRV_Deployment\AppData\Local\Temp\61e3d867-9d07-41cc-91c1-c4a04717bc2d
2022-01-14T07:19:22.6340311Z .ps1'"
2022-01-14T07:19:22.6340436Z 
2022-01-14T07:19:22.7446332Z ls : Access is denied
2022-01-14T07:19:22.7446823Z At line:1 char:1
2022-01-14T07:19:22.7447184Z + & 'C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe' -NoLogo ...
2022-01-14T07:19:22.7447867Z + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2022-01-14T07:19:22.7448434Z     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ls : Access is denied:String) [], 
2022-01-14T07:19:22.7448858Z     RemoteException
2022-01-14T07:19:22.7449188Z     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
2022-01-14T07:19:22.7449545Z  
2022-01-14T07:19:22.7449643Z 
2022-01-14T07:19:22.7618724Z At E:\DeploymentTeam\Scripts\DeploymentValidation\Test.ps1:1 char:1
2022-01-14T07:19:22.7619629Z + ls "\\Server\builds\PACKAGES\MainMasterBuildDrop\ ...
2022-01-14T07:19:22.7620370Z + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2022-01-14T07:19:22.7620732Z 
2022-01-14T07:19:22.7620874Z 
2022-01-14T07:19:22.7731192Z     + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (\\ServerName\...edBuild\axmo
2022-01-14T07:19:22.7731830Z del:String) [Get-ChildItem], Unauthoriz 
2022-01-14T07:19:22.7732125Z 
2022-01-14T07:19:22.7732299Z 
2022-01-14T07:19:22.7845365Z    edAccessException
2022-01-14T07:19:22.7845602Z 
2022-01-14T07:19:22.7846744Z 
2022-01-14T07:19:22.7966282Z     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemExistsUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.Power
2022-01-14T07:19:22.7966826Z Shell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
2022-01-14T07:19:22.7966978Z 
2022-01-14T07:19:22.7967080Z
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: As you can see the error it is denying permission for the account you are using.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60259172/how-can-we-copy-or-download-files-from-windows-share-pathunc-to-linux-servers

Comment: @DillyB, As you can see from the screenshot I attached, the user has required permissions to the UNC path. but still I am getting a permission denied error.

Comment: does your az devops pipeline has the same user id  for deployment?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml this where you can find service connection used to deploy resources in azure, but the same is not used for authenticating windows file share

Comment: Well the agents are running with the user I mentioned before. And this user has all the access. but still not working. Screenshot attached for reference.

Comment: As per the image I believe self hosted agent is used here, I only once used Invoke-Command with user credentials to modify a file content in a file server. But, instead of using the share path I used the literal path like E:\sharename\filename. I was not sure this is the right way to do, but I was able to complete my task. I also upvoted your question, because it was something new to me as well.